# WPF JumpList is not working in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, jump-list

I am trying to run custom commands from TaskBar using JumpTask in Windows 10 but it does not start the linked application. However it correctly displays the JumpTask link and it's icons. Here is the code that works correctly in Win7/Win8.

```
JumpTask signOutTask = new JumpTask
{
    ApplicationPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location,
    Title = XXX.Properties.Resources.AccountContextMenu_SignOutText,
    Description = "Sign out of your account",
    CustomCategory = "Actions",
    Arguments = "/signout",
    IconResourcePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location,
    IconResourceIndex = 0
};

JumpList jumpList = new JumpList();
jumpList.JumpItems.Add(signOutTask);
jumpList.ShowFrequentCategory = false;
jumpList.ShowRecentCategory = false;

JumpList.SetJumpList(Application.Current, jumpList);
```

Comment: I can confirm the same issue - similar code that was working on Windows 8.1 is no longer working on Windows 10.

Comment: Hi Collin, have you had a chance to address this ?

Comment: It seems like it's more than just WPF apps - the Skype jump list no longer works. I tested by setting the jump list start program to notepad.exe and it still didn't work, so the jump list just isn't executing anymore, it seems.

Comment: ON the other hand in my Visual Studio recent items are still there.

Comment: I have Skype working properly. But my jump list, with the same code of the question, not working yet. Did any one solve it?

Comment: Does anyone know anything new about this? Our app jumplist used to work on Win 7, but as in your case it stopped working on Win 10. Do not recall how it did on Win 8.1. TA

Comment: We just tested with a MS (retired) sample from Win 7 SDK, and it does **not** work as well. Sample described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), actual code can be downloaded [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-7-Taskbar-Single-4120eafd)

Comment: We've discovered that once application is pinned to taskbar JumpList starts working.

Comment: We solved the problem by signing the build.

Comment: @grimcoder so does app need to be both signed (by creator) and pinned (by user) in order to have custom activities/tasks in jump list working again?

Comment: I found JumpLists work in the taskbar (pinned or not) but not in the start bar. This is with Windows10 Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.286)

Answer (score 2):

You need to update to Windows 10 Build 1511 (10586).

JumpLists will Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I could get mine to work again by modifying the Arguments property passed along to the application. I used the format @QUIT@, etc. to distinguish them from other parameters.

It seems like Win10 doesn't like the @ character, so I switched my parameters to |QUIT| and it works again.

You are using "/signout", so I tested /QUIT. That works on Win8.1 and Win10 for me.

I would still try removing special characters or using different ones and see if that makes a difference in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem trying to implement a JumpList under Win10.  With my app, I could add JumpList tasks with no problem ... they just wouldn't do anything.  **The really odd thing is that the JumpList started to work after I had Pinned my app to the task bar.**  Repeated the experiment multiple times with the same result.  App unpinned, JumpList didn't work ... App pinned, JumpList worked fine.

So, I tried the same experiment with FireFox and Excel.  Both of these have no problem executing JumpList tasks ... Pinned or UnPinned.

Clearly we are missing something.  Not sure what.